# the attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold error in SharePoint list update

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem

I am facing this error while doing Update list. In update list I am using
**"List.ResetRoleInheritance()"**. Is this effect anything to cause this error.
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
 List destList = Context.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(destListId));
        destList.ResetRoleInheritance();
        destList.Update();
        Context.Load(destList, new Expression<Func<List, object>>[0]);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery + Rest API ? or C# code ?

Comment: I'm using c# (csom)

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"List.ResetRoleInheritance()"** will give **Threshold error**

When that list having items more that threshold limit and that are inheriting permissions from parent means list.
That list having unique permissions.
Then I tried to update the list and included "List. ResetRoleInheritance ()" so every file/item inheriting from that list will change accordingly. In this case **Threshold error**  will come.